# get video metadata information

Tags: video, metadata

Any tool in ruby or Command line interface to get all the metadata associated with a video file.

I need to store the metadata in the table for indexing purposes.

I tried using ffmpeg and but the metadata is not formatted.

Comment: Check this link: http://snippets.aktagon.com/snippets/136-How-to-extract-video-metadata-with-mplayer-and-Ruby

Answer (score 1):

`ffmpeg -i` normally gets the job done, however, there's a Ruby tool that manipulates metadata; It will even output the data as xml, which can be useful

See [here](http://rubyforge.org/frs/?group_id=1096&release_id=9694here)

Comment: When I used ffmpeg for this purpose, I got a warning that ffmpeg is deprecated in favor of avconv. This command worked exactly the same after installation: `avconv -i filename.mpg`

Comment: See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/9477756/297323 That error message is very missleading.