# What are the differences and similarities between ffmpeg, libav, and avconv?

Tags: ubuntu, audio, ffmpeg, libavcodec, libav

When I run `ffmpeg` on Ubuntu, it shows:

```
$ ffmpeg 
ffmpeg version v0.8, Copyright (c) 2000-2011 the Libav developers
  built on Feb 28 2012 13:27:36 with gcc 4.6.1
This program is not developed anymore and is only provided for compatibility. Use avconv instead (see Changelog for the list of incompatible changes).
```

Or it shows (depending on the Ubuntu version):

```
$ ffmpeg
ffmpeg version 0.8.5-6:0.8.5-0ubuntu0.12.10.1, Copyright (c) 2000-2012 the Libav developers
  built on Jan 24 2013 14:49:20 with gcc 4.7.2
*** THIS PROGRAM IS DEPRECATED ***
This program is only provided for compatibility and will be removed in a future release. Please use avconv instead.
```

I found avconv on http://libav.org. I am just perplexed by them.

Comment: This implies that you are giving wrong command line arguments.

Comment: ```This program is not developed anymore and is only provided for compatibility. Use avconv instead ```

Comment: What are you trying to do? `ffmpeg` is library mostly and main `ffmpeg` commandline is more for demonstration of its features (though it doesn't matter that you use if it helps). If you want to use only as a command, there are many applications that use ffmpeg to do what you want to do.

Comment: There is a helpful explanation of the whole deal at http://blog.pkh.me/p/13-the-ffmpeg-libav-situation.html

Comment: I cannot tell you all the differences, but: avconv -ss 00:01:42 -t 00:00:32 -i sourcefilename -acodec copy targetfilename does not work, and ffmpeg -ss 00:01:42 -t 00:00:32 -i sourcefilename -acodec copy targetfilename does work as expected even though the documentations match

Answer (score 507, accepted):

## Libav is dead

Last commit was on 2019-08-21 and they shut down the git repo. Use FFmpeg.

## Confusing messages

The messages mentioned in the question are rather misleading and understandably a source of confusion.

The fork was basically a non-amicable result of conflicting personalities and development styles within the FFmpeg community.

## The real `ffmpeg` vs the fake one

For a while both Libav and FFmpeg separately developed their own version of `ffmpeg`.

Libav then renamed their bizarro `ffmpeg` to `avconv` to distance themselves from the FFmpeg project. During the transition period the "not developed anymore" message was displayed to tell users to start using `avconv` instead of their counterfeit version of `ffmpeg`. This confused users into thinking that FFmpeg (the project) is dead, which is not true. A bad choice of words, but I can't imagine Libav not expecting such a response by general users.

This message was removed upstream when the fake "`ffmpeg`" was finally removed from the Libav source.

In June 2012, [the message was re-worded](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libav/+bug/939863) in Ubuntu for the package `libav - 4:0.8.3-0ubuntu0.12.04.1`. Unfortunately the new "deprecated" message has caused additional user confusion.

Starting with Ubuntu 15.04 "Vivid Vervet", FFmpeg's `ffmpeg` is [returned to the repositories](https://packages.ubuntu.com/vivid/ffmpeg).

## libav vs Libav

To further complicate matters, Libav chose a name that was historically used by FFmpeg to refer to its libraries (libavcodec, libavformat, etc). For example the [libav-user mailing list](https://ffmpeg.org/mailman/listinfo/libav-user/), for questions and discussions about using the FFmpeg libraries, is unrelated to the Libav project.

## How to tell the difference

If you are using `avconv` then you are using Libav. If you are using `ffmpeg` you could be using FFmpeg or Libav. Refer to the first line in the console output to tell the difference: the copyright notice will either mention FFmpeg or Libav.

Secondly, the version numbering schemes differ. Each of the FFmpeg or Libav libraries contains a `version.h` header which shows a version number. FFmpeg will end in three digits, such as 57.67.**100**, and Libav will end in one digit such as 57.67.**0**. You can also view the library version numbers by running `ffmpeg` or `avconv` and viewing the console output.

## Also see

For an interesting blog article on the situation, as well as a discussion about the main technical differences between the projects, see [The FFmpeg/Libav situation](http://blog.pkh.me/p/13-the-ffmpeg-libav-situation.html).

Comment: looks like it's a personal issue

Comment: If even after installing the real ffmpeg you are not able to get it working. You should remove default ffmpeg shipped with ubuntu as libav-tools, see : http://askubuntu.com/questions/162740/how-do-i-uninstall-ffmpeg.

Comment: @user568109 It depends on how you installed ffmpeg. See [How to Compile FFmpeg on Ubuntu, Debian, or Mint](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/UbuntuCompilationGuide) or just use a [Linux build of `ffmpeg`](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html#LinuxBuilds). Either of these methods should work if the repository package is also installed.

Comment: I did build ffmpeg but when running ffmpeg from terminal the one shipped default was running and doing apt-get remove ffmpeg did not remove it. So I left a message for those stuck with this issue, just to clear the confusion. It is shipped as libav-tools.

Comment: It seems like some "trademark" system is needed in the open-source community to avoid these situations !!!

Comment: An additional note: Libav refused to incorporate any changes from FFmpeg, but FFmpeg was perfectly happy to take Libav's fixes, so FFmpeg was usually the better software.

Comment: Also Libav seems to be dead now (last commit Aug 2019), while FFmpeg continues active development