# Storing high quality video stream (from IP Action Camera) continuously to a Storage Device and issues around Write-Speed bottlenecks

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, video-streaming, video-processing, rtsp

I am looking to get an Action Camera (Eken H8R, or a GoPro) for a project. Let me explain the scenario I have:

I will obtain a live stream from the camera on to a Raspberry Pi (over WiFi) as shown [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jeOlpAQ7tAM). Next, I want to continuously segment this live stream into 10-15 minute video clips and store them in an external Hard Drive (which is connected to the RPi). I am considering [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10459338/save-continuous-rtsp-stream-to-5-10-minute-long-mp4-files) thread, and the `avconv`command mentioned in the answer by Alexander.

Now, my concern is write-speed limitations. The video stream would probably have a high bitrate, and might be 4k30fps, in which case file sizes would be **huge**. Would write speed to disk be a bottleneck? If so, how will the Pi maintain a buffer to achieve this? Could I run out of space as the memory stick on the Pi would only be around 8 gigs? If so, what's a better alternative? Please correct me if I'm wrong on these as I'm only a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

I only have experience with GoPro cameras, not Eken.
Depending on the GoPro, you can get a 432*240 stream (if you purchase a any GoPro with wifi except HERO5) or a 848*480 stream (if you buy a HERO5).
The livestreaming procedures are explained here: https://github.com/KonradIT/goprowifihack/blob/10708f26ca96bdb14bc4c1f350393c182ca1508f/HERO4/Livestreaming.md

Basically you need to have the GoPro keep alive script running in a terminal while on another terminal you can use ffmpeg to save 10 minute chunks (you need to emulate ^C after 10 minutes). Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your time. However, this still does not answer my question. Are there any write speed limitations when writing to disk? Also, can you not get the 4k output written to file?

Comment: You cannot get a livestream in 4K, only 432*240 or 848*480 (HERO5).