# How can I create a video file from a directory of images in Python

Tags: python, opencv

```
import cv2
import cv2.cv as cv
import glob
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
filelist = glob.glob('./*.jpg')

isColor = 1
fps     = 25  # or 30, frames per second
frameW  = 256 # images width
frameH  = 256 # images height
writer = cv2.VideoWriter('test1.avi',-1, 25.0, (640,480))

#-----------------------------
#Writing the video file:
#-----------------------------

nFrames = 10; #number of frames
for i in range(nFrames):
    img = np.array([np.array(Image.open(i)) for i in filelist])
#img = cv.LoadImage("image%d.jpg"%i) #specify filename and the extension
#add the frame to the video
#cv2.cv.WriteFrame(writer,img)
    writer.write(img)

VideoWriter = None #
```

when I run this code the following error occurs

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Buddhi/Desktop/New folder/Create Mp4.py", line 24, in <module>
    writer.write(img)
error: ..\..\..\..\opencv\modules\core\src\matrix.cpp:524: error: (-215) dims <= 2 in function cv::Mat::operator struct _IplImage
```

Why is this? Please help me.

Comment: The error indicates that the image file may be corrupted or not present

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe not a direct answer to the question, but are you sure you're using the right tool for the job?

I've found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13590976/python-make-a-video-using-several-png-images), which explains how you can use ffmpeg to convert images into a video. Depending on your use case, you might consider using Python to organize the images and call ffmpeg, of course.

Comment: Thank You ! I'll try on that.

Comment: You're welcome :) As an addition: you can call other programs and functions from within Python using, for instance, `shell` or `subprocess`, to keep everything in one script.

Comment: This should not be the accepted answer as it misses the Python part. Can surely be a recommendation rather.