# Error during use of ffmpeg for the joining of images to form a video file

Tags: python, python-2.7, ffmpeg

I am trying to join a sequence of images (`*.png`) using `ffmpeg`. The filenames of the images are in the following format: `recon_0001.png,  recon_0002.png, ... , recon_0100.png`. I would like to join the images sequentially (i.e. `recon_0001.png` being the first frame, `recon_0002.png` the second frame and so on.)

After looking at the following link: [Python: Make a video using several .png images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13590976/python-make-a-video-using-several-png-images) , I tried to implement my task using the following code:

```
from __future__ import division
import cv2
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pylab import pcolor, show, colorbar, xticks, yticks
import numpy as np

if(1):
    ffmpeg -f image2 -r 1/5 -i /Users/Username/Folder/recon_%04d.png -vcodec mpeg4 -y movie.mp4
```

But, I get the following error:

```
ffmpeg -f image2 -r 1/5 -i /Users/Username/Folder/recon_%04d.png -vcodec mpeg4 -y movie.mp4
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What am I missing here? I am new to the use of `ffmpeg` and I will really appreciate any help.

Comment: The `ffmpeg` command is valid and should execute just fine in a command-line interface, but you don't need `-f image2` and `-r` should be `-framerate`. The log/console output from the command will be informative if an output file is not created.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard: Thanks for the reply. But, I still get the same error after implementing your suggestion (Error: `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`)

Comment: That's not a message from `ffmpeg`, so I'm guessing it's a python issue. You should show your actual code.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard : I added my code now. Is there something that I am missing in my code?

Comment: I'm not sure. I'm not a python user, but I thought it would be useful for others who do know python to see your script.

Answer (score 0):

you need to import the "os" module and put the ffmpeg command in "os.system("ffmpeg command")"
python doesnt automatically run terminal commands so you have to specify that with os.system