# cannot import module imageio in python3

Tags: python-3.x, python-imageio

Using python3, I am unable to import the imageio module into my python program, which I need, as I try to animate a list of PNG images I have.  Thus far I have tried:

"pip3 install imageio" both running as myself and as root.  The install succeeded, but it still errors out as in the subject line.  I suppose I could try "apt-get install (package name)", but need to determine the package_name.

Any ideas more than welcome - TIA.

Comment: My mistake.  I typed imageio into the tag space and it must have expanded to javax.imageio.  It should just be "imageio".  For reference, found this snippet of code elsewhere on stackoverflow for doing animation of gif files:     import imageio
ims = [imageio.imread(f) for f in list_of_im_paths]
imageio.mimwrite(path_to_save_gif, ims)

Comment: I found a way to do it without imageio (just matplotlib) at stackoverflow:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61716066/creating-an-animation-out-of-matplotlib-pngs

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Comment: import imageio
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'imageio'

Comment: Sounds like you are installing it for a different version of python than you are using later on. Have you tried `python -m pip install imageio` or - if you are on a UNIX system - `python3 -m pip install imageio`? (if you are using conda or venv this might also affect things)

Comment: Thanks so much for that.  I succeeded with "python3 -m pip install imageio" in that it installed imageio, and now when I run the python code and "import imageio" I don't see the import error any longer.  Greatly appreciate it!

Comment: I am having a similar issue. I also can't import imageio from a venv. I have tried `subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, '-m', 'pip', '-q', 'install', '--user', '--force-reinstall', '--upgrade', 'imageio'])` to try and install it for the user and the embedded python executable, but still cannot import.

Answer (score 4):

Try importing the last version.

```
import imageio.v3 as iio

im = iio.imread('imageio:chelsea.png')
print(im.shape)  # (300, 451, 3)
```

ref https://imageio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples.html