# ffmpeg/ffprobe show_frames option

Tags: ffmpeg, ffprobe

I recently installed ffmpeg version 0.8.5-4:0.8.5 on my Ubuntu Linux box.

When I execute "ffprobe -show_frames http://test.com/test.mp4" I get the following error:

**Unrecognized option 'show_frames'**

I have tried installed all sorts of ffmpeg dependent packages to fix this without any success.

Can someone help to resolve this error by telling me what I need to install exactly to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: So, is there any equivalent option to get the total number of frames using `avprobe` ?

Answer (score 12):

You're using a crippled, fake version of "ffprobe" that originates from libav, not FFmpeg:

Ubuntu switched from FFmpeg to libav because the Debian/Ubuntu ffmpeg package maintainer is a libav developer. The intentional usage of the names "ffmpeg" and "ffprobe" for something not from FFmpeg was disappointing, and is misguiding to users and misrepresents the work of the FFmpeg developers. Also see [Who can tell me the difference and relation between ffmpeg, libav, and avconv?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9477756/1109017)

This bizarro "ffprobe" does not have the `-show_frames` option. You have three options:

- [Compile `ffmpeg` and/or `ffprobe`](https://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/UbuntuCompilationGuide)
- [Use Jon Severinsson's FFmpeg PPA](https://launchpad.net/~jon-severinsson/+archive/ffmpeg)
- [Use a static build of `ffmpeg`](http://ffmpeg.gusari.org/static/)

All three methods will provide a real, working `ffprobe`. Use the static build if you're lazy.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstalled the current version of ffmpeg(This was a static build downloaded from the ffmpeg site: http://ffmpeg.gusari.org/static/32bit/

show_frames option was deprecated in this version.

Download and installed the latest version from:http://www.ffmpeg.org/releases/ffmpeg-1.1.3.tar.bz2