# After converting FLV to MP4 format using ffmpeg the MP4 file has 0 bytes

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, flv

Using `ffmpeg` I converted an FLV file to an MP4 file. But the MP4 file has 0 bytes. The command which i used to convert is

```
ffmpeg -i sample.flv -b 1104k -ab 122k sample.mp4
```

This is the output I got for the above ffmpeg command:

```
ffmpeg version 0.8.5-4:0.8.5-0ubuntu0.12.04.1, Copyright (c) 2000-2012 the Libav developers
  built on Jan 24 2013 18:01:36 with gcc 4.6.3
*** THIS PROGRAM IS DEPRECATED ***
This program is only provided for compatibility and will be removed in a future release. Please use avconv instead.
[flv @ 0x64f7a0] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Input #0, flv, from '/home/kirthiga/Desktop/videopine/test.flv':
  Metadata:
    creationdate    : Thu Mar 28 12:46:29
  Duration: 00:00:09.82, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0.0: Video: flv, yuv420p, 320x240, 1k tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc
    Stream #0.1: Audio: nellymoser, 22050 Hz, mono, s16
[buffer @ 0x64f720] w:320 h:240 pixfmt:yuv420p
encoder 'aac' is experimental and might produce bad results.
Add '-strict experimental' if you want to use it.
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you're using an outdated, misnamed and broken version of `ffmpeg` that's actually not from FFmpeg, but from Libav, an FFmpeg fork. [Read this for more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9477115/who-can-tell-me-the-difference-and-relation-between-ffmpeg-libav-and-avconv/9477756#9477756).

The error is that your version—for some reason—doesn't seem to be configured with any additional libraries, and thus you'll have a hard time actually converting with proper quality to anything useful.

To get your command working, a `-strict experimental` should do, but what I propose instead is that you either [download a recent static build](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html) of FFmpeg, or [compile it yourself](http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/CompilationGuide) with dependencies such as `libfdk_aac` and `libx264`.

You can then do:

```
ffmpeg -i in.flv -crf 23 -c:v libx264 -c:a libfdk_aac -vbr 4 out.mp4
```

Change the CRF parameter between 18 and 28 to control the quality. Less means better, 23 is default. For audio, the quality is set with the VBR option, with 4 delivering roughly 128 kBit/s stereo, and values from 1 to 5 (higher means better).

If you really have to use constant bitrate, try this instead:

```
ffmpeg -i in.flv -c:v libx264 -b:v 1104K -c:a libfdk_aac -b:a 122k out.mp4
```

See the [x264 encoding guide](http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/x264EncodingGuide) and [AAC encoding guide](http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/AACEncodingGuide) on the FFmpeg wiki for more options.