# How to generate images from mp4 file?

Tags: php, image, ffmpeg

I am trying to generate the `images` from `mp4` video file with `ffmpeg`.

I only want the first 3 second of every video in the file.

I have the following command..

```
 $videoFile = $mp4File; //I have many mp4 files

 $ffmpeg ="/usr/ffmpeg";

 $image_path = $videoFile;

 $ALL_PLACE_WIDTH = 300;
 $ALL_PLACE_HEIGHT = 220;

 $image_cmd = " -r 1 -r 0.03 -s ".$ALL_PLACE_WIDTH."x".$ALL_PLACE_HEIGHT." -f image2 ";
 $dest_path = 'project/image-%01d.png';

 $str_command= $ffmpeg  ." -i " . $image_path . $image_cmd .$dest_path;
 shell_exec($str_command);
```

I am trying to generate firt 3 second image of every `mp4` file but my script will genearte a lot of images and it create images across entire `mp4` file.

Can I restrict the script to get only the first 3 seconds images only? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you want one image from three seconds in.

Change:

```
$image_cmd = " -r 1 -r 0.03 -s ".$ALL_PLACE_WIDTH."x".$ALL_PLACE_HEIGHT." -f image2 ";
```

to:

```
$image_cmd = " -vf scale=".$ALL_PLACE_WIDTH.":-1 -frames:v 1 -ss 3 ";
```

What's different?

- `-r` and `-f image2` are not required.
- The [scale filter](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#scale) can automatically adjust the height or width with `-1` in relation to your given value so aspect is preserved. This avoids stretching or squishing that could result from an absolute resize. This means that `$ALL_PLACE_HEIGHT = 220;` is not needed.
- Use `-frames:v 1` to output one frame.
- `-ss` is the offset time, or the time that you want the image from.

Comment: Thanks for help. I got an error...Unrecognized option 'frames:v'
Failed to set value '1' for option 'frames:v'  +1

Comment: @FlyingCat You are using an old version. My example uses recent syntax.

Comment: Do you know how to do this in old version?

Comment: @FlyingCat I'm not sure what version you're using.

Comment: @LordNectbear   my ffmpeg version 0.8.6-4:0.8.6-0

Comment: @FlyingCat Unfortunately that is a "fake" ffmpeg from a fork of FFmpeg (see [Who can tell me the difference and relation between ffmpeg, libav, and avconv?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9477756/1109017)). I don't use it so I can't give any suggestions but maybe some other user can.

Comment: @FlyingCat `-vframes` should work on the version you're using.