# What version of FFMPEG should I use on DEBIAN to transcode RTSP to RTMP?

Tags: ffmpeg

I was using that command:

```
   ffmpeg -i rtsp://login:password@90.70.42.54:554/axis-media/media.amp -f flv  rtmp://localhost:1935/live/yarek
```

**WHich worked fine on 1 windows**,

This command gives errors on linux1
(ffmpeg version 0.8.6-4:0.8.6

```
WriteN, RTMP send error 10053 (129 bytes)
WriteN, RTMP send error 10053 (45 bytes)
WriteN, RTMP send error 10038 (42 bytes)
av_interleaved_write_frame(): Operation not permitted
```

and gives errors on Linux2: (ffmpeg version 0.7.15)

```
[h264 @ 0x98e2f80] RTP: PT=60: bad cseq c54f expected=b90c
[h264 @ 0x98e2f80] RTP: PT=60: bad cseq b90c expected=c551
[h264 @ 0x98e2f80] RTP: PT=60: bad cseq c552 expected=b90f
[rtsp @ 0x98de5e0] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate

Seems stream 0 codec frame rate differs from container frame rate: 180000.00 (180000/1) -> 90000.00 (180000/2)
Input #0, rtsp, from 'rtsp://login:password@90.70.42.54:554/axis-media/media.amp':
  Metadata:
    title           : Media Presentation
  Duration: N/A, start: -4756.582667, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0.0: Video: h264 (Main), yuvj420p, 1024x768 [PAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 90k tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc
```

**So I am 100% sure that the command line is GOOD, but FFMPEG is bad.**

My question is: **What version of FFMPEG should I use on DEBIAN to transcode RTSP to RTMP** ?

Can someone recommend me a CORRECT version of FFMPEG that works ?

Regards

Comment: Consider adding `-codec copy` as an output option if you want to [stream copy](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) instead of re-encoding.

Answer (score 0):

The `ffmpeg` you are using in Windows is probably from the FFmpeg project via [Zeranoe's FFmpeg Windows builds](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/), and the so-called `ffmpeg` you are using in Debian is probably from a fork of FFmpeg called libav. I could confirm this if you included the console outputs for each command. See:

- [Who can tell me the difference and relation between ffmpeg, libav, and avconv?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9477756/1109017)
- [libav vs ffmpeg - better to use libav (avconv) today?](https://superuser.com/a/507473/110524)
- [The FFmpeg/Libav situation](http://blog.pkh.me/p/13-the-ffmpeg-libav-situation.html)

I recommend using real `ffmpeg` since the version from the fork is obviously buggy. You have two main choices:

- Follow a step-by-step guide to [compile `ffmpeg` on Debian](https://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/UbuntuCompilationGuide), or
- Simply download and use an already compiled recent [Linux build of `ffmpeg`](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html#LinuxBuilds)

Compiling will embiggen your nerd cred, but using the build is lazier.