# How to add album art with ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, albumart

I've been stuck in adding album art to mp3 files.

I've already researched and Googled this issue but haven't found a solution yet. The [`ffmpeg` documentation](http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#mp3) recommends this script to add image (album art) to mp3:

```bash
ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -i cover.png -c copy -map 0 -map 1 -metadata:s:v title="Album cover" -metadata:s:v comment="Cover (Front)" out.mp3
```

But it doesn't work. My console output is:

```
Unrecognized option 'c'
Failed to set value 'copy' for option 'c'
```

I looked for another solution and got [this](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/2221):

```bash
ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -i cover.png -map 0:0 -map 1:0 -c copy -id3v2_version 3 -metadata:s:v title="Album cover" -metadata:s:v comment="Cover (Front)" out.mp3
```

This returns the same output:

```
Unrecognized option 'c'
Failed to set value 'copy' for option 'c'
```

Anybody can help me, please?

I am using ubuntu 12.04 and ffmpeg version 0.8.6-4:0.8.6-0.

Thanks.

Comment: just about the -c ? have you try '-acodec copy' as you use an old version... and try to update !

Comment: I already tried to replace -c with -codec but return of output is same :
Unrecognized option 'codec'
Failed to set value 'copy' for option 'codec'

Comment: You're using an old, fake version of ffmpeg that is not supported by the online documentation. See [Who can tell me the difference and relation between ffmpeg, libav, and avconv?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9477756/1109017). You can get recent, real ffmpeg by following a [step-by-step guide to compile ffmpeg](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/UbuntuCompilationGuide), or by simply using a [Linux build of ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html#LinuxBuilds).

Answer (score 65):

With Recent version,

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp3 -i test.png -map 0:0 -map 1:0 -c copy -id3v2_version 3 -metadata:s:v title="Album cover" -metadata:s:v comment="Cover (front)" out.mp3
```

Use `-map` to associate input stream to the output
Use `-c copy` to directly demux/remux
The `-id3v2_version 3` is what is missing in your command line. Note that that wil write an IDV2.3 but you can ask for a 2.4 (`-id3v2_version 4`)

with the `-id3v2_version 3` option the `-metadata`option will be well interpreted

**Note:** the metadata comment is case-sensitive.

Comment: One '-metadata:s:v' option above was lacking the '-'. This gave me an error "[NULL @ 0x7ffd7400fa00] Unable to find a suitable output format for 'metadata:s:v' || metadata:s:v: Invalid argument". I corrected it in the answer.

Comment: _comment="Cover (front)"_  - not _comment="Cover (Front)"_

Comment: I have to say that should not skip the "-id3v2_version 3" parameter. Without it the cover will be visible on Mac, but not on Windows.

Comment: Using this method album art shows in some programs (vlc and totem) but not in others (rhythmbox and nautilus) which normally show album art for mp3 files.

Answer (score 24):

There is an important thing to notice here, that made me loose an hour of work:

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp3 -i test.jpeg -map 0:0 -map 1:0 -codec copy -id3v2_version 3 \ 
-metadata:s:v title="Album cover" -metadata:s:v comment="Cover (front)" out.mp3
```

The `f` in `comment="Cover (front)"` must be lowercase. If not, the picture type in the ID3 header will not be set !

Another hint that might help somebody: To avoid that a JPEG cover image is converted to png, you have to set `-codec copy`.

Answer (score 8):

This is how I converted a **different input/source format** (in this example *video.ts*) to MP3 and also added cover art to the result MP3 all in one go (one command):

```bash
ffmpeg -ss 5 -to 13 -i video.ts -i logo.png -map 0:a -map 1:0 -c:1 copy -b:a 320k -id3v2_version 3 -metadata:s:v title="Album cover" -metadata:s:v comment="Cover (front)" result.mp3
```

#### NOTE

If ffmpeg fails with an error, try to omit `-metadata:s:v title="Album cover" -metadata:s:v comment="Cover (front)"` from the command.

#### Description of options used in the command:

| Option | Required? | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `-ss 5` | *OPTIONAL* | specifies the start time (in seconds) from the input |
| `-to 13` | *OPTIONAL* | specifies the end time (in seconds) from the input |
| `-i video.ts` | - | the first input (file to convert) |
| `-i logo.png` | - | the second input (album/cover art) |
| `-map 0:a` | - | from the input `0` (aka *video.ts*), selects the audio (`a`) |
| `-map 1:0` | - | from the input `1` (aka *logo.png*), selects the first stream (`0`) |
| `-c:1 copy` | *OPTIONAL* | sets the codec for second input (image) to `copy` (no conversion) |
| `b:a 320k` | *OPTIONAL* | sets the bitrate for audio stream to `320k`; see accepted values in footnote [1](https://#1) |

Thanks to *konsolebox* for [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24840831/8583692).

[1](https://#1):  Valid bitrates for `b:a` option:
`8k`|`16k`|`24k`|`32k`|`40k`|`48k`|`64k`|`80k`|`96k`|`112k`|`128k`|`160k`|`192k`|`224k`|`256k`|`320k`

Answer (score 3):

the problem is that you are not defining what codec you want to copy. In case of the audio should be `-c:a copy` the cover is recognized as video (go figure!!), so `-c:v copy`

```
ffmpeg -i audio-in.mp3 -i picture.png -c:a copy -c:v copy -map 0:0 -map 1:0 -id3v2_version 3 -metadata:s:v title="Album cover" -metadata:s:v comment="Cover (front)" audio-out.mp3
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't comment but Mahozad's answer did the trick for me, just adding -map 0:a (instead of just "0" or "0:0") and -map 1:0 without anything else:

`ffmpeg -i url.m3u8 -i url.jpg -map 0:a -map 1:0 file:output.mp3`