# FFmpeg video to MP3 with album art

Tags: video, ffmpeg, mp3, albumart

I can convert a video to MP3 using FFmpeg with the following:

```bash
ffmpeg -i input -vol %volume% -y -acodec libmp3lame -ab %quality%k output
```

I have a static image file *cover.jpg*.

I want to use *cover.jpg* as album art with the converted audio which can be done by another command:

```bash
ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -i cover.jpg -map_metadata 0 -map 0 -map 1 output.mp3
```

But instead of using two commands, I need to use one command to convert the video to MP3 and embed the *cover.jpg* as album art.

How can I do this? Perhaps there is a way to do this by `libmp3lame` option?

I am lifting my hairs with this, please help.

Thank You.

Comment: I am still looking for a way to do this. It seems that I cant use lame options with libmp3lame (like --ti albumart.jpg) .. it returns an error. Some help please.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add album art with ffmpeg?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18710992/how-to-add-album-art-with-ffmpeg)

Comment: [This new answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73706680/8583692) may be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

(Moderator: please set this as a comment.  I don't have the rep.)

What is the reason for needing it as a single command?  Would putting those two commands into a batch script, using a temporary file, suffice?

Comment: Hello Byron, Thank you for replying. I am editing an existing script. This script sends the command only once, then process the output in other stages. I do not have the coding knowledge to modify the entire script. My only option is somehow do it in that single line.