# How to record audio with ffmpeg on linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, audio, ffmpeg

I'd like to record audio from my microphone.  My OS is ubuntu.  I've tried the following and got errors

```
$ ffmpeg -f alsa -ac 2 -i hw:1,0 -itsoffset 00:00:00.5 -f video4linux2 -s 320x240 -r 25 /dev/video0 out.mpg

ffmpeg version 0.8.8-4:0.8.8-0ubuntu0.12.04.1, Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the Libav
developers
  built on Oct 22 2013 12:31:55 with gcc 4.6.3
*** THIS PROGRAM IS DEPRECATED ***
This program is only provided for compatibility and will be removed in a future release.
Please use avconv instead.
ALSA lib conf.c:3314:(snd_config_hooks_call) Cannot open shared library
libasound_module_conf_pulse.so
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM hw:1,0
[alsa @ 0xbda7a0] cannot open audio device hw:1,0 (No such file or directory)
hw:1,0: Input/output error
```

Then I tried

```
$ ffmpeg -f oss -i /dev/dsp audio.mp3

ffmpeg version 0.8.8-4:0.8.8-0ubuntu0.12.04.1, Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the Libav
developers
built on Oct 22 2013 12:31:55 with gcc 4.6.3
*** THIS PROGRAM IS DEPRECATED ***
This program is only provided for compatibility and will be removed in a future release.
Please use avconv instead.
[oss @ 0x1ba57a0] /dev/dsp: No such file or directory
/dev/dsp: Input/output error
```

I haven't been able to get ffmpeg to find my microphone.  How can I tell ffmpeg to record from my microphone?
It seems the 'Deprecated' message can be ignored because of [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9477115/who-can-tell-me-the-difference-and-relation-between-ffmpeg-libav-and-avconv/9477756#9477756)

Comment: You need to include the complete ffmpeg console output along with each command.

Comment: Ok I added everything.  Does this help?

Comment: What's the output of: `arecord -l`

Comment: yes arecord output working? ref: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AudioCapture

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Unix & Linux (unix.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I realise this is a bit old. Just in case anyone else is looking:

```
ffmpeg -f alsa -ac 2 -i default -itsoffset 00:00:00.5 -f video4linux2 -s 320x240 -r 25 -i /dev/video0 out.mpg
```

This way it will use the default device to record from. You were also missing a *-i* before the video capture device - **/dev/device0**

If you want to get more specific you should take a look in **/proc/asound**.
Check the **cards**, **devices**, **pcm** files and the **card** subdirectories. You should be able to glean enough information there to be able to make an educated guess; e.g **hw:1,0** or **hw:2,0**

The documentation may provide further clues:

- http://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/DeviceNames

The same goes for the webcam - it may not be **/dev/video0**, perhaps you have an external webcam plugged in and its at **/dev/video1** - Have a look in the **/dev** directory and see whats available

Comment: When using pulse audio, it's useful to be able to select exactly which audio device to record. `ffmpeg -sources pulse` will list the available pulse sources. In my case the one I wanted was the system's default mixed sound output device (`alsa_output.usb-Burr-Brown_from_TI_USB_Audio_CODEC-00.analog-stereo.monitor`). The ffmpeg command then becomes: `ffmpeg -i pulse -ac 2 -i 'alsa_output.usb-Burr-Brown_from_TI_USB_Audio_CODEC-00.analog-stereo.monitor'`

Answer (score 2):

solved !

```
ffmpeg -f pulse -ac 2 -i default -f x11grab -r 30 -s 1920x1080 -i :0.0 -acodec pcm_s16le -vcodec libx264 -preset ultrafast -threads 0 -y /media/t/TBVolume/desktop/output.mkv
```

Comment: It would be helpful to others to also provide a brief description explaining how this solves the problem.

Answer (score -2):

First, list your AV devices using:

```
ffmpeg -list_devices true -f dshow -i dummy
```

Assuming your audio device is "Microphone Array", you can use:

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -i audio="Microphone Array" -c:a libmp3lame -b:a 128k OUTPUT.mp3
```

Here, 128k is the sampling rate. You can check all options for sampling rates (CBR) [here](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/MP3).

Comment: Question is about Linux, but your answer is for Windows.

Comment: The "dshow" can be replaced with "avfoundation" for it to work with Linux and Mac OS.

Comment: @KeithBennett avfoundation is only for macOS/iOS. Linux can use alsa and pulse.