# ffmpeg on Heroku: unrecognized option 'preset'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, video, heroku, ffmpeg

I'm using ffmpeg version 1.2.4 in my local Rails app to convert video files.  Everything works as expected when I run the app locally.  When I deployed to heroku, I added a buildpack for ffmpeg:

https://github.com/shunjikonishi/heroku-buildpack-ffmpeg

This installs ffmpeg version git-2013-06-02-5711e4f.  When I try to transcode a video to mp4, I get the following error:

**Unrecognized option 'preset'. Error splitting the argument list: Option not found**

Here is the complete log:

```
2013-11-17T19:45:05.255059+00:00 app[web.1]: Running transcoding...
2013-11-17T19:45:05.255059+00:00 app[web.1]: ffmpeg -y -i /app/public/uploads/tmp/1384717504-2-9158/Untitled.mov -vcodec libx264 -acodec libfaac -s 640x360  -qscale 0 -preset slow -g 30 -aspect 1.7777777777777777 /app/public/uploads/tmp/1384717504-2-9158/tmpfile.mp4
2013-11-17T19:45:05.255059+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-11-17T19:45:05.317895+00:00 app[web.1]: Failed encoding...
2013-11-17T19:45:05.317895+00:00 app[web.1]: ffmpeg -y -i /app/public/uploads/tmp/1384717504-2-9158/Untitled.mov -vcodec libx264 -acodec libfaac -s 640x360  -qscale 0 -preset slow -g 30 -aspect 1.7777777777777777 /app/public/uploads/tmp/1384717504-2-9158/tmpfile.mp4
2013-11-17T19:45:05.317895+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-11-17T19:45:05.317895+00:00 app[web.1]: ffmpeg version git-2013-06-02-5711e4f Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
2013-11-17T19:45:05.317895+00:00 app[web.1]:   built on Jun  2 2013 07:38:40 with gcc 4.4.3 (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5.1)
2013-11-17T19:45:05.317895+00:00 app[web.1]:   configuration: --enable-shared --disable-asm --prefix=/app/vendor/ffmpeg
2013-11-17T19:45:05.317895+00:00 app[web.1]:   libavutil      52. 34.100 / 52. 34.100
2013-11-17T19:45:05.317895+00:00 app[web.1]:   libavcodec     55. 13.100 / 55. 13.100
2013-11-17T19:45:05.317895+00:00 app[web.1]:   libavformat    55.  8.102 / 55.  8.102
2013-11-17T19:45:05.317895+00:00 app[web.1]:   libavdevice    55.  2.100 / 55.  2.100
2013-11-17T19:45:05.318137+00:00 app[web.1]:   libavfilter     3. 74.101 /  3. 74.101
2013-11-17T19:45:05.318137+00:00 app[web.1]:   libswscale      2.  3.100 /  2.  3.100
2013-11-17T19:45:05.318137+00:00 app[web.1]:   libswresample   0. 17.102 /  0. 17.102
2013-11-17T19:45:05.318137+00:00 app[web.1]: Unrecognized option 'preset'.
2013-11-17T19:45:05.318137+00:00 app[web.1]: Error splitting the argument list: Option not found
2013-11-17T19:45:05.318137+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-11-17T19:45:05.318137+00:00 app[web.1]: Errors: no output file created.
```

I think that the error may be a result of differences in the version of ffmpeg that I'm using locally and on Heroku.  Does anyone have suggestions for how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're trying to use the encoders libfaac and libx264, but your ffmpeg was not compiled to support these encoders. libfaac requires ffmpeg configure options  `--enable-nonfree --enable-libfaac` and libx264 requires `--enable-gpl --enable-libx264`. Using `--disable-asm` is not recommended and can significantly affect encoding time.

If you need help compiling see [How to Compile FFmpeg on Ubuntu](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/UbuntuCompilationGuide). Compilation is recommended because the so-called "ffmpeg" package in the repository is a fake, old, buggy, and outdated [version from a fork](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9477756/1109017) and it does not supply a good AAC encoder.

As for the ffmpeg command options:

- `-qscale` is ambiguous. You should tell ffmpeg if it should apply to the audio (`-qscale:a` or `-q:a`) or the video (`-qscale:v` or `-q:v`) but note that libx264 ignores `-qscale` and you should use the default settings or `-crf` as shown in the [FFmpeg and x264 Encoding Guide](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/x264EncodingGuide).
- No need to add `-g 30 -aspect 1.7777777777777777`. The default setting for `-g` should suffice and I don't see why you want to force a seemingly arbitrary aspect ratio.
- Consider using `-vf scale=640:-1` instead of explicitly forcing a hard size since this can change the aspect ratio and cause a squished or stretched look. The `-1` tells ffmpeg to automatically calculate the value while preserving the aspect ratio.
- If you compile ffmpeg, then use `-codec:a libfdk_aac` instead of `libfaac`. It will provide better quality per bitrate. See the [FFmpeg and AAC Encoding Guide](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/AACEncodingGuide) for more info.
- I'm guessing you are making videos for display on the web. If yes, then add `-movflags +faststart` as an output option to allow the client to begin playback before the file is completely downloaded. This is only available with real ffmpeg and not the fake junk.

Comment: thanks very much for your help!  I'm actually using the carrierwave-video gem, so that's what's generating the ffmpeg encoding options.  I'm not sure how to specify options for ffmpeg when using the heroku buildpack; do you have pointers for how to install ffmpeg on heroku?

Comment: @scientiffic No, sorry, but it's definitely a problem with the lack of configuration options (and therefore possible lack of installation of each required external library such as x264 and faac).

Comment: @scientiffic Did you ever come up with a solution to this? I know it's been awhile but we're seeing the same issue on Heroku.

Comment: @MichaelPaladino I actually wrote a gist about what I ended up doing: https://gist.github.com/ttseng/7682321

Comment: @scientiffic I recommend using libfdk_aac instead of libfaac. Better quality per bitrate.