# avconv much longer than ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, libav, avconv

I was using ffmpeg to generate some images from a video. Now I read that I shouldn't use ffmpeg longer and use avconv from libav instead.
So I tried to do the same thing with avconv.

The ffmpeg is looking like this:

```
ffmpeg -ss 1000 -t 5 -i 'test.mp4' -s '120*90' -r 10 out%2d.bmp
```

Same with avconv:

```
avconv -ss 1000 -t 5 -i 'test.mp4' -s '120*90' -r 10 out%2d.bmp
```

ffmpeg needs less than one second to finish. Avconv about 90 seconds for the same task.
Is this usual or do I need to change some things to work with avconv?

Comment: `ffmpeg` from FFmpeg is under very active development. Libav, a fork of FFmpeg, had their own fake "`ffmpeg`" which they then deprecated for `avconv`. See [Who can tell me the difference and relation between ffmpeg, libav, and avconv?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9477756/1109017) for more info.

Comment: possibly they're encoding to different video encoding? (I agree libav saying ffmpeg is deprecated is lame, though, in their defense, they're also in active development AFAIK)