# In libav "rtmp://url live=1" is not working as in FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, libavcodec, avconv

I am trying to play live rtmp stream, streamed via Red5 server. 
Command used is 
**ffmpeg -i "rtmp://IP/live/1234 live=1" -f flv rtmp://IP/live/1234_56**

The above command for  live streaming works well with ffmpeg on Window OS. But unable to stream live rtmp video below command is run on libav ,Ubuntu OS using avconv tool.

**avconv -i "rtmp://IP/live/1234 live=1" -f flv rtmp://IP/live/1234_56**

Even i used *rtmp_live* AVOption to play live stream or to replace live=1 parameter as given below-
**avconv -i "rtmp://IP/live/1234 rtmp_live" -f flv rtmp://IP/live/1234_56**

But this command doesn't work. Please tell me how to use rtmp_live or live=1 with avconv tool

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you just use `ffmpeg` (the one from FFmpeg, not the fake one from libav)? You can [download a Linux build of `ffmpeg`](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html#LinuxBuilds) or follow a step-by-step [guide to compile `ffmpeg`](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/UbuntuCompilationGuide).

Comment: FFmpeg is depricated in Ubuntu 12.4 and above versions. Therefore I am trying it with libav.

Comment: FFmpeg is the name of a project. It is not deprecated. `ffmpeg` is the name of a command-line tool offered by both FFmpeg and a fork named libav. The fake `ffmpeg` from libav has been deprecated. Yes, it is confusing, but this was intended by libav. They chose names already used be FFmpeg (the cli tools, the libraries, and even the word "libav" which historically referred to the whole collection of FFmpeg libraries). See [Who can tell me the difference and relation between ffmpeg, libav, and avconv?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9477756/1109017)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

```
ffmpeg -i "rtmp://IP/live/1234?live=1" -f flv rtmp://IP/live/1234_56
```