# Encoding all videos to MP4 and lowering resolution with Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, video, encoding, ffmpeg, mp4

I have a web server based on Ubuntu 12.04, the user can upload a video (whatever the format/container/codec it is) then i want to convert it to an MP4 video. I tried ffmpeg without good result (and now it is also deprecated).

How i can do this?

The important is also to reduce the resolution for HD videos for reduce video's size.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The fake "`ffmpeg`" from Libav (a fork of FFmpeg) has been deprecated by Libav for their program `avconv`. Development activity for `ffmpeg` from FFmpeg has always been, and continues to be, very active. Few can deny that the "deprecated" message was misleading to users.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9477115/who-can-tell-me-the-difference-and-relation-between-ffmpeg-libav-and-avconv/9477756#9477756).

ffmpeg is not deprecated. You are probably receiving misleading information. 
ffmpeg will work great for what you want to do. I suggest you take a second try. You can use it from PHP or Java for example and execute it through command line. It is particularly fitted for batch processing and any media-based automated task.

The option to resize in ffmpeg is `-s` (see [here](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html) for more info).

If you are really not convince with that I suggest you take a look [handbrake](http://handbrake.fr/downloads.php) which also has a command line interface for Ubuntu. Handbrake is mostly a wrapper for ffmpeg (with a GUI also).

After that there are paid options like [zencoder](http://zencoder.com/en/) which has a great cloud-based API. A more comprehensive list is [here](http://www.streamingmedia.com/Articles/Editorial/Featured-Articles/The-2012-Encoding-and-Transcoding-Buyers-Guide-84210.aspx).

I hope you get what you are looking for. If you have any issue with ffmpeg please post your code and console output on a new question.