# Convert PNGs to webm video with transparency

Tags: video, ffmpeg, webm, avconv

I would like to use `avconv` to convert a series of PNG images to a WebM video, preserving transparency.

I understand that the pixel format used in the output video must support transparency. So I tried:

$ avconv -framerate 25 -f image2 -i frames/%03d.png -pix_fmt yuva420p output.webm

Unfortunately, `avconv` complains:

`Incompatible pixel format 'yuva420p' for codec 'libvpx-vp9', auto-selecting format 'yuv420p'`

I am using `ffmpeg version 2.8.4-1+b1 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers`.

Comment: [avconv != ffmpeg](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9477115/5726027)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

With VP8:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 25 -f image2 -i frames/%03d.png -c:v libvpx -pix_fmt yuva420p output.webm
```

Edit: Now, with VP9

```
ffmpeg -framerate 25 -f image2 -i frames/%03d.png -c:v libvpx-vp9 -pix_fmt yuva420p output.webm
```

Comment: Thanks for the insight. Can't get it to work though, if I run your command, avconv complains that `Specified pix_fmt is not supported`. I am using `avconv version 9.18-6:9.18-0ubuntu0.14.04.1, Copyright (c) 2000-2014`

Comment: Switch to a recent ffmpeg build and try.

Comment: Still no luck. I am using `avconv version 11.3-6:11.3-1~trusty` now and still get `Specified pix_fmt is not supported`.

Comment: In your answer (updated now) you wrote `avconv` instead of `ffmpeg`. So I used `avconv`, too. Working with ffmpeg, thanks!

Comment: I needed to use '-metadata:s:v:0 alpha_mode="1"' as mentioned [here](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/VP8) to get alpha to work for VP8.

Comment: Works here, without. Which version of ffmpeg and libvpx?

Comment: For anyone frustrated on Ubuntu LTS: VP9+alpha doesn't work on ffmpeg 2.8.x, you should get ffmpeg 3.x.

Comment: Works for me, but produces an output with garbage quality. How do you set a decent quality or configure the bitrate?

Comment: Set the bitrate e.g. `-b:v 2M` for 2 mbps.

Answer (score 15):

Since [2016-07-13](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/commit/acca56d9629b7fc158ce188190d22314c3d92c39), it's possible to encode *VP9/webm* videos with alpha channel (*VP9a*).

You only need a copy of **ffmpeg** compiled after that date. By the way, all you need to write is:

```
ffmpeg -i frames/%03d.png output.webm
```

**FFmpeg** understands png format and will set a default framerate of 25 fps and a `yuva420p` pixel format to the output.

Comment: I added `-b:v 800k` for an increased video bit rate to get a better image quality. The default wasn't good enough.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. ffmpeg 4.3.2, video doesn't transparent.

Answer (score 1):

You can also convert a video wich allready contains an alpha channel to a webm video with transparency with this command:

```
ffmpeg -i myVideoWithAlphaChannel.mov -c:v libvpx -vf format=rgba myVideoWithAlphaChannel.mov.webm
```

The format of **myVideoWithAlphaChannel.mov** (generated with Blender3D) is:

- "Quicktime" format
- "PNG" Codec

With as Ouputs:

- H.264
- RGBA

[Here Blender 3D rendering configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/riqUm.jpg)