# ffmpeg -bsf:v h264_mp4 toannexb not working in debien

Tags: video, ffmpeg

i have to append video with a audio and merge the output with anther video mp4 
i use this code to append video with audio

```
ffmpeg -i "out1.mp4" -i "desc1.mp3" -c:v copy -c:a aac -strict experimental "output2.mp4"
```

its work in windows but in my server lunix i have this error

```
root@ns:~# ffmpeg -i /var/www/hespress/17/out1.mp4 -i /var/www/hespress/17/desc1.mp3 -c:v copy -c:a aac -strict experimental /var/www/hespress/17/output2.mp4
ffmpeg version 0.8.20-6:0.8.20-0+deb7u1, Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the Libav developers
  built on Jan 19 2017 11:13:36 with gcc 4.7.2
The ffmpeg program is only provided for script compatibility and will be removed
in a future release. It has been deprecated in the Libav project to allow for
incompatible command line syntax improvements in its replacement called avconv
(see Changelog for details). Please use avconv instead.
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/var/www/hespress/17/out1.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf53.21.1
  Duration: 00:00:20.03, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1374 kb/s
    Stream #0.0(und): Video: h264 (Main), yuvj420p, 1280x720 [PAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 1371 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 30 tbn, 60 tbc
[mp3 @ 0xa06c40] max_analyze_duration reached
Input #1, mp3, from '/var/www/hespress/17/desc1.mp3':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf53.21.1
  Duration: 00:00:19.53, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 192 kb/s
    Stream #1.0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, mono, s16, 192 kb/s
Unrecognized option 'c:v'
Failed to set value 'copy' for option 'c:v'
```

when i went to merge two file i use this code

```
ffmpeg -i intro.mp4 -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts '.$dossier.'/intermediate1.ts
```

in windows  its work but in server debian i have this error

```
root@ns205125:~# ffmpeg -i /var/www/hespress/intro.mp4 -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts /var/www/hespress/17/intermediate1.ts
ffmpeg version 0.8.20-6:0.8.20-0+deb7u1, Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the Libav developers
  built on Jan 19 2017 11:13:36 with gcc 4.7.2
The ffmpeg program is only provided for script compatibility and will be removed
in a future release. It has been deprecated in the Libav project to allow for
incompatible command line syntax improvements in its replacement called avconv
(see Changelog for details). Please use avconv instead.
[aac @ 0x3938ba0] Input buffer exhausted before END element found

Seems stream 0 codec frame rate differs from container frame rate: 180000.00 (180000/1) -> 30.00 (30/1)
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/var/www/hespress/intro.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isommp42
    creation_time   : 2017-03-27 23:03:04
  Duration: 00:00:12.92, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2598 kb/s
    Stream #0.0(eng): Video: h264 (Baseline), yuv420p, 1280x720, 2479 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2017-03-27 23:03:04
    Stream #0.1(eng): Audio: aac, 48000 Hz, mono, s16, 127 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2017-03-27 23:03:04
Unrecognized option 'c'
Failed to set value 'copy' for option 'c'
root@ns205125:~#
```

Comment: How i can install this ?

Comment: 1000 tankyou i use this https://gist.github.com/jmsaavedra/62bbcd20d40bcddf27ac

Comment: That gist is mostly OK, but needlessly pollutes your system with unnecessary symlinks. I added a better method in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Problem

You're using the [ancient, dead, buggy, broken, useless, counterfeit "`ffmpeg`" from Libav](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9477115/what-are-the-differences-and-similarities-between-ffmpeg-libav-and-avconv/9477756#9477756), not a modern, real `ffmpeg` from FFmpeg.

## Solution

Fortunately you can easily [download](https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/) a recent version of the real thing and use it instead:

1. Download

   ```
   wget https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/builds/ffmpeg-git-64bit-static.tar.xz
   ```
2. Extract

   ```
   tar xvf https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/builds/ffmpeg-git-64bit-static.tar.xz
   ```
3. Copy the binary files to `/usr/local/bin`

   ```
   sudo cp ffmpeg-git-*-64bit-static/ff* /usr/local/bin
   ```

**Now you can run the `ffmpeg` command and it should use your downloaded version.**

4. (optional) To undo/uninstall just delete the FFmpeg binaries from `/usr/local/bin`.

   ```
   sudo rm -f /usr/local/bin/{ffmpeg,ffmpeg-10bit,ffprobe,ffserver}
   ```

#### Notes

- You can keep any existing *ffmpeg* package from the repository for other packages that may depend on it.
- If the `ffmpeg` command still executes the old, crappy version then your current shell session is remembering the old location. Run `hash -r` or just log-out/log-in. You'll only need to do that once.
- If you prefer, you can [compile `ffmpeg`](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu) instead of relying on a third-party to provide a binary.
- If you only want or need a single user to execute `ffmpeg` then you can put it in `~/bin` instead of `/usr/local/bin`. Then run `source ~/.profile` to refresh the `PATH` or just log-out/log-in (you'll only need to do this once). This also works if you do not have root or superuser privileges.