# Avconv / FFmpeg - VOB to mp4

Tags: video, ffmpeg, avconv

I am using avconv/ffmpeg to convert VOB files copied from a DVD to mp4. The command I'm using is

```
avconv -i "concat:1.VOB|2.VOB|3.VOB|4.VOB|5.VOB" -c:v libx264 -crf 28 -c:a libvo_aacenc -b:a 128k output.mp4
```

This is working, but I've seen many different commands using different kinds of arguments, and I'm wondering if this is the "right" way to do it, and if someone has suggestions about which arguments I should (not) use and why (not). The file should be compatible with mobile devices and smart TV's. I've also seen "libmp3lame" being used as audio codec, is it better to use AAC or MP3?

The file size is 732.6MB for a video lasting 00:58:37, is this reasonable?
 Maybe I can use something to reduce the filesize further without too much quality loss?

I'm also confused about the difference between Avconv and FFmpeg. I thought that FFmpeg is deprecated and Avconv is "newer and better", I have two installations of Linux Mint, when I run "avconv --help" on a 17.1 installations I see

```
avconv version 9.20-6:9.20-0ubuntu0.14.04.1, Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the Libav developers
```

And when I run the same command on a 18.1 installation I see

```
ffmpeg version 2.8.11-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
```

Is avconv newer than ffmpeg or is it just a different name for the same thing?

Comment: I see. On my 18.1 distro avconv is just a symlink to ffmpeg. That explains some of my confusion, thanks. Any suggestions on the command I'm using?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

VOB files can be strange beasts, so to concatenate VOB with `ffmpeg` it is often recommended to use the `dvd2concat` tool included in the FFmpeg source code. However, it's not available in the repository, but you can just download it. Also, the 2.8 release branch is old, so upgrade your `ffmpeg` too. Here's how:

```
sudo apt install lsdvd
mkdir ~/bin
cd ~/bin
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/master/tools/dvd2concat
chmod +x dvd2concat
wget https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/builds/ffmpeg-git-64bit-static.tar.xz
tar xvf ffmpeg-git-64bit-static.tar.xz
mv ffmpeg-git*/ff* .
source ~/.profile
```

If you ever want to undo any of this:

```
sudo apt remove lsdvd
rm -rf ~/bin/ff*
hash -r
```

Now run the encoding commands:

```
dvd2concat /path/to/vob/files dvd.concat
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -protocol_whitelist "file,subfile" -i dvd.concat -vf format=yadif,yuv420p -c:v libx264 -crf 28 -c:a aac -b:a 128k -movflags +faststart -metadata title="Movie Title" output.mp4
```

Note the console output from `dvd2concat`/`lsdvd` is not that informative, so check to see that it actually created `dvd.concat`. This is a text file that `ffmpeg` will use to refer to the input VOB files.

> The file should be compatible with mobile devices and smart TV's.

Adding the `-profile:v main` output option will help with compatibility for older devices. If your hardware is fairly modern you can omit `-profile:v` to allow x264 to automatically choose the profile.

See [FFmpeg Wiki: H.264](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264) for more info.

> I've also seen "libmp3lame" being used as audio codec, is it better to use AAC or MP3?

AAC. I've seen a few players have issues with certain MP4 files containing MP3 audio.

See [FFmpeg Wiki: AAC](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/AAC) for encoding suggestions.

> The file size is 732.6MB for a video lasting 00:58:37, is this reasonable?

It is not possible to guess the output file size when using `-crf`. File size will depend on the encoding complexity of the input, the duration, and the encoding options used.

> Maybe I can use something to reduce the filesize further without too much quality loss?

Increase the `-crf` value for a lower quality and therefore a smaller file size. If you must target a specific output file size use two-pass encoding. Otherwise, just stick with single-pass using `-crf` like 99% of us usually do. See [FFmpeg Wiki: H.264](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264) for more info.

> I'm also confused about the difference between Avconv and FFmpeg. I thought that FFmpeg is deprecated and Avconv is "newer and better". Is avconv newer than ffmpeg or is it just a different name for the same thing?

The FFmpeg project, nor it's `ffmpeg` command-line tool, were ever deprecated. That message was from the Libav fork referring to their own short-lived, fake "`ffmpeg`" tool. Libav didn't differentiate between FFmpeg/real `ffmpeg` and their fake "`ffmpeg`" which was understandably confusing to general users. For more info see:

- [Why was ffmpeg removed from Debian?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/243945/42712)
- [What are the differences and similarities between ffmpeg, libav, and avconv?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9477756/1109017)

Comment: Thanks a lot! But I believe you forgot `wget ` in the 6th command for upgrading ffmpeg :)
The `source ~/bin` give me the error `bash: source: /home/oneup/bin: is a directory` but when I run `./ffmpeg` in the `bin` directory it's working :)

Comment: @0ne_Up You're right about `wget`. Added (one month late).

Comment: *concat* should also be whiltelisted: ```-protocol_whitelist "file,subfile,concat"``` at least for macos, because of only first part will be included in final video.

Comment: For me line `wget https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/builds/ffmpeg-git-64bit-static.tar.xz` didn't work. I replaced in the filename `64bit` with `amd64` (also in the next command). See https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/ for the list of files

Comment: Also, the last command: `ffmpeg [...] -vf format=yadif,yuv420p [...]` didn't work, but using `format=pix_fmts=yuv420p` like [in ffmpeg examples](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#format-1) it did