# ffmpeg can't transcode DVD ac3 audio stream, but VLC can play it

Tags: ffmpeg, aac, dvd

I'm attempting to transcode a DVD to a single MKV file. I've had success in the past with other DVDs, but I'm running into an error I haven't seen before.

First I concatenate the VOB files I want to transcode:

```
cat VTS_02_1.VOB VTS_02_2.VOB VTS_02_3.VOB > WMAV.VOB
```

`ffprobe` output:

```
$ ffprobe -analyzeduration 100M -probesize 100M WMAV.VOB                                                                         Input #0, mpeg, from 'WMAV.VOB':
  Duration: 01:05:19.42, start: 0.300300, bitrate: 5686 kb/s
    Stream #0:0[0x1bf]: Data: dvd_nav_packet
    Stream #0:1[0x1e0]: Video: mpeg2video (Main), yuv420p(tv, smpte170m, top first), 720x480 [SAR 32:27 DAR 16:9], 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 90k tbn, 59.94 tbc
    Stream #0:2[0x80]: Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 192 kb/s
Unsupported codec with id 100357 for input stream 0
```

Then I run this command to transcode the file:

```
ffmpeg -analyzeduration 100M -probesize 100M \
  -i WMAV.VOB \
  -map 0:1 -map 0:2 \
  -c:v libx264 -preset slow -tune film -crf 21 \
  -c:a aac -b:a 192k \
  wmav.mkv
```

However, when I include `-c:a aac`, I get thousands of errors like this:

```
Error while decoding stream #0:2: Error number -16976906 occurred
[ac3 @ 000002bd24d8eec0] expacc 127 is out-of-range
[ac3 @ 000002bd24d8eec0] error decoding the audio block
```

There doesn't seem to be any issue with the audio stream since it plays back fine in VLC. The transcode succeeds if I use `-c:a copy`.

What is causing this error and how could I fix the problem?

Comment: My guess is the VOBs are still encrypted (VLC can play encrypted DVDs with decss, ffmpeg can’t). If so, you need to run decss on the files.

Comment: You omitted the version info which is useful info. It's best to always include the complete log. The VOBs may have arbitrary type/number/order of streams which may cause issues. See if [dvd2concat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45870091/1109017) helps (assuming DRM/CSS/encryption is not the issue).

Comment: Hello, I have the same problem with TV mpeg recordings, investigating I found that it is caused by corrupted audio problems in frames, were you able to solve it?