# FFmpeg vs Libav vs libVLC vs Gstreamer as of 2018

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, gstreamer, libvlc

I am trying to do some video processing on real time. I was beginning to try the FFmpeg, but I saw this question:

[Why would I choose Libav over FFmpeg, or is there even a difference?](https://superuser.com/questions/507386/why-would-i-choose-libav-over-ffmpeg-or-is-there-even-a-difference)

Which further links to this question:

[What are the differences and similarities between ffmpeg, libav, and avconv?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9477115/what-are-the-differences-and-similarities-between-ffmpeg-libav-and-avconv/9477756#9477756)

and this blog post:

http://blog.pkh.me/p/13-the-ffmpeg-libav-situation.html

After reading this I came to know that Libav is a fork from FFmpeg and is being developed separately. I am need of developing C++ application using either Libav or FFmpeg or libVLC or Gstreamer. I think there has been a lot of changes after these questions are answered. It would be great to have some benchmark on these tools.

Do you guys have any preference of one over another, any benchmark results for video and audio processing? I need to process frames fast and stream a video to multiple C++ applications, what would be the best way to solve this problem and what will be the best tool to choose ?

So as of 2018 what is the current status of these tools on video processing.
It would be nice to know some results from the people working on video processing who are familiar with these tools.

Comment: You are forget about GStreamer

Comment: @RSATom Thank you - I will edit.

Comment: Great question, unfortunately open questions are not tolerated here so it'll just be blocked. If you have more success elsewhere please post a forwarding link.

Comment: I wrote an article about it some time ago: http://www.ulduzsoft.com/2016/06/qtmultimedia-ffmpeg-gstreamer-comparing-multimedia-frameworks/ - it doesn't cover VLC but covers QtMultimedia. Essentially you will unlikely find any major difference in performance; GStreamer for example can use libav as decoder. One thing I like GStreamer for is backward compatibility; FFMpeg deprecates its APIs all the time, and you'd have to keep modifying your code every time someone renamed a function/option.

Comment: @GeorgeY. - The thing with me is that I have a stream from a monocular camera, I have to share the video to multiple C++ applications, based on your experience which tool will be great for this task. Thank you.

Comment: "Sharing a stream with multiple C++ applications" doesn't tell much about what your requirements are, and why you need media frameworks at all.